# Count returns more rows after insert into

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I have a table in impala and I am running the below query:

```
INSERT INTO db.test1
PARTITION(a,b,c,d,e,f)
select distinct * from db.test2
where a = 201011;
```

The `target(db.test1)` table has more rows than the `source(db.test2)`. How is this possible? I am using also select distinct.

Comment: Perhaps some rows already exist in the table.

Comment: The target table was new. It supposed to be a copy of source table.

Comment: Supposed to be new.  Check the table first, then run your insert, to see whats in there.  Or if it is supposed to be empty when it gets here truncate it just before doing the insert.

Comment: Use `insert overwrite xx select *from myxx` instead. Also invalidate metadata xx after insert to make sure you're using latest copy of table